# How can you attach a file from one email straight to another one?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Say I've received a message *M* from Licia, containing file `foo.txt`. Later I write a not directly related mail *N* to Robert, but want to attach `foo.txt`.

Is there a way to do this without opening *M*, explicitly saving `foo.txt` in some temporary location, switching to *N* again and going to the temporary file to attach it?

Comment: Yes;  Most desktop clients will attach the attachment if you forward the email.

Comment: Of course, but that's not what I'm asking about. I want to re-attach a file to an _unrelated_ mail (which may itself be a reply to something else).

Comment: Isn't it easier to forward the email with the attachment then copy and paste the text of the other emal?

Comment: Certainly not in case the email I'm writing has multiple recipients and/or additional attachments that are already selected.

Comment: I suppose you could write an add-on to do what you want.

Comment: In outlook, it is possible to drag and drop it directly from one email to another as txt file attached in your case.

Comment: @Scorpion99 ...
I guess I should use GUI applications every once in a while like normal people do, so I'll come up with such a ridiculously obvious solution. Yeah: indeed drag&drop works in Thunderbird too. Will you make that an answer?